# How to make a Core 2 Duo processor look like a single processor?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have a board that does not work if it detects that the processor is core 2 duo how can I make the core 2 duo to be detected as a single processor?

Comment: what do you mean by "board"? add-in card? motherboard?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are talking about a motherboard not accepting a Core 2 Duo processor...

The most likely scenario is that the motherboard is not compatible with Core 2 Duo processors. This is not due to the number of cores but the type of processor not suiting your motherboard. There is no trick to make a Core 2 Duo look like an older model processor.

Check your motherboard manufacturer's web site for a list of supported processors. Depending on the age of your motherboard, it may be as simple as a firmware upgrade to support Core 2 Duo or it may not be possible at all.

To get a better answer here you'll have to provide the manufacturer/model of your motherboard and the model number of your Core 2 Duo. The current BIOS version on your motherboard would also help.

Comment: It's doubtful that the CPU socket on the motherboard is compatible.

Comment: @harrymc: It's quite likely that it's a LGA775 board originally designed for the P4 Prescott, as he is asking this question. It's possible that such a board can support a C2D with a BIOS update.

Comment: @jason404: Without knowing his motherboard model, I can't answer.

Comment: Jason404 is right, there are many S775 M/B, for example 915G chipset, that do not support C2D, or even Pentium D, even with a BIOS update.

Comment: I bought a C2D as soon as they were released. I put it on a Asus P5W DH Deluxe motherboard, which I had bought several months before. I had to update the BIOS, and it worked very well (it was the best motherboard for the C2D for several months, in fact).